# How do you restore a user from windows.old?

Tags: windows, user-accounts, restore, windows.old

How do I take a user account from windows.old and make it usable on the version of Windows currently being booted? Both versions are Windows 10, though I doubt this affects it much.

Comment: There is no official "restore" process, all you can do is copy out any data you need from the Windows.old user account folder.

Comment: Can this be used to make an old account usable again, or only to transfer old files to an existing account on the new Windows install?
Basically, if I copy an entire folder from windows.old\Users\ , would that user account work?

Comment: Only to harvest files.